# Scientific notaton when I paste into Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, squirrel-sql

I am not sure of this is a problem related with Excel or SQuirrel SQL.

I have the following problem when I extract data from SQuirrel and "Paste" it into an excel spreadsheet.

My column, "SOME_FIELD" represent a list of random alpha numeric / numeric element that has  "text" as format.

[image]

But when I scroll down and check for the others elements I see some with in scientific notation., like you can see below *NUMBER+E+11*

[image]

At the top there is the number without the "E+11"

The solution to this issue is to change the format of the entire columns to "text" before pasting the data from SQuirrel.
I am curious why this occurs for some elements and not for the rest...

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/413226/why-does-excel-treat-long-numeric-strings-as-scientific-notation-even-after-chan